Hall and Knight or G. Chrystal for algebra
I recently finished studying calculus from N. Piskunov's Integral and Differential calculus. It was much more rigorous than anything I've been exposed to.
I am looking to get the same treatment for algebra. I have heard similar things about George Chrystal and Hall and Knight's books, but I am unsure of which to pick. Can someone point out the differences between these books?

Chrystal's and Hall/Knight's books are not especially known for being rigorous, at least in the proof sense, but rather they are known for their inclusion of topics and problems that make use of a high level of algebraic manipulation. Also, unless you're preparing for contest math, or wish to expand your knowledge of school algebra (which a prospective high school teacher might wish to do), these two books are more appropriate as prerequisites for calculus (although far less than what's in these two books is actually needed for calculus, even Spivak's calculus text).
